# usage of the idiom "dead sure"

Tags: idioms

I'm filling my linkedIn profile and in the summary I'm about to add the following text:

> I’ve always been fascinated by the opportunities brought by the digital age. Now when it’s easier than ever to connect with people instantly and anywhere, gain knowledge and skills previously only accessible by limited groups of people and existence of the machines that save and improve lives for billions, (...)

wouldn't it be informal or strange in any way for a native speaker to see the idiom "dead sure" following it, like:

> and I'm **dead sure** that I want to get involved.

Comment: in the sense of 0% or 100% sure?

Comment: yes, in the sense of 0% or 100% sure. Is there anything else it could imply?

Comment: i'd use 'unsure' then. btw can you explain your 2nd sentence to me

Comment: @Oscar I think what JonMark Perry is asking is whether you mean **totally unsure** or **totally sure**.  Usually, "dead sure" means **totally sure** (100% sure).  I addressed that situation in my answer.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Thanks. Also, I can see he hasn't been able to understand the message in the 2nd sentence, is it unclear or ambiguous in any way?

Comment: @Oscar the second sentence is a run-on sentence.  Because it's very long and addresses many different issues, it is confusing.  However, stack exchange has a policy against proofreading, so it would be off-topic to discuss in too much detail.  If you have a specific question about how it's worded, you could post another question in ell.stackexchange.com and I could look at it there.  Also, feel free to upvote an answer that you like, if you want to. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** that would be a bit too informal for a professional profile.

Check out [this article](https://www.ragan.com/Main/Articles/4_rules_for_using_idioms_in_your_writing__42852.aspx) on idiom use and when it's appropriate or inappropriate in a professional setting.

You could say that you have **no doubt** that you want to get involved.

Another synonym for "dead sure" would just be **certain.**

Also, since you're asking for the perspective of a native speaker, you might be better off asking questions like this on ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why is ELL supposedly the place for perspectives of a native speaker?

Comment: @Xanne I suppose I was inferring that because the OP asked what a native speaker would think, they might not be one themselves.  And ELL does have a lot of questions asking what native speakers use in certain situations, especially on topics like idioms.  Was I out of place appending that to my answer?

Comment: On looking over the OP's question, it's probably a good suggestion--not because that's the place to get the perspective of a native speaker (which is provided here in abundance, with many dialects) but because the OP's second sentence doesn't parse, as JohnMark Perry implies.

Comment: Really? What does any of you think is wrong with that second sentence, please? Granted, the informality doesn't suit the earlier style but what's that to do with anything?